# Schedule emails in Django using Celery and Amazon SES

Tags: python, django, email, celery

I'm finding very difficult to schedule emails in Django. I've been researching on the Internet but haven't been able to figure this out yet. Perhaps you can give me a hand on this or at least point me out in the right direction to find out how to do it.

For instance, when you use [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com), you can specify sending an email like this:

```
def send_scheduled_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>",
              "to": "bar@example.com",
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!",
              "o:deliverytime": "Fri, 25 Oct 2011 23:10:10 -0000"})
```

I would like to have something similar en Django to send emails where I can specify a delivery time, like in the previous case.

So far, I have installed [django-SES](https://github.com/hmarr/django-ses) and I'm able to send emails via Amazon SES. I have also installed [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) and used to have django-celery as well but it seems it is no longer required starting with Celery 3.1.

To sum up, how do I use `send_mail`to tell Celery to wait for a specific date and time to give the emails to django-SES so they can delivered on time?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: [Periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) could be of use to you?

Answer (score 2):

Write a Python script and schedule a cron job :) Why does the the application server need to know about an e-mailer job?  And if it does, notify it with a shared data store with ACID compliance.

These ideas are encapsulated in a really good architecture practice, [separation of mechanism from policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_mechanism_and_policy).

Basically we have following:

1. The mechanism may be database and policy will be the data stored in your database that indicates what e-mail and when to send it.
2. The next mechanism is the python script and the policy is the code in the python script. This should at least do the work, and indicate failure or success.
3. The third is the "cronjob" where the policy of when to send is contained in the crontab and the mechanism is the cron daemon that reads the crontab and triggers the effect.

Sure, sometimes complete separation is not achieved, but partial separation is better then a tightly coupled mess. And the best part is each of these is also decoupled from each other (for the most part, except perhaps through the internet or the operating system).

Celery is a really big hammer for some complex problems, and big hammers should be avoided IMHO.  Django is a big hammer in a way too, and it solves many simpler problems, but in a way that is appropriate for a big group of people (the real problem I think it is trying to solve, but you have to be judge on whether or not its the right tool for the job at hand).

Once you've gone through the steps above, each of which is a pretty straight forward task, you'll have a nice solution that is easy to understand in its individual parts and therefore easy to modify, extend, and replace.

Comment: Do you think cron jobs are better than using Celery for this case? Why?

Comment: I would actually need to know a lot more about your problem and environment.  Are you sending 10,0000,000 emails an hour? How often do you need this to run? Is time of the essence for getting the e-mail out?  I just assumed because you didn't mention these things, it was probably a simple case, where simple abstractions could be utilized effectively.  It's better in this case because it will be faster to implement and understand and maintain. When you need to switch to celery, you can and will have better understanding of why you might need to.

Comment: And I mention switching, and some imply this is a waste of time, which is not true.  The hardest part is the requirements and your simple python e-mailer script will encapsulate almost all of the requirements nicely, and once you add a tough requirement that requires celery, you're that much further along and can reuse that knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Derek. I have about 5,000 users and I need to schedule a reminder of each of them early in the morning, every day. So it's sending 5,000 personalised emails everyday day at about the same time or a windows of time (e.g. from 5am to 6am).

Comment: Yeah, cron can do that easily.  Test it by making the simple script first and see if it meets your needs (error handling, logging, etc.), you don't even need to hook up cron or send that many e-mails to get started testing.  If you super paranoid send a notification when the cronjob is done running, and if it doesn't show up, something is wrong :) Iterate from there and make it better and better for your personal needs.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I agree with Derek Litz's answer.  But, depending on your requirements, you might want to look at using cron + Django management command.  If it's a really simple, text based email then I'd probably go with Derek's solution.  But, if the email is HTML based or needs to be dynamic for each user, then I would probably leverage the power of django's models and templating engine.  I do this kind of thing pretty often, and it works well.

Comment: You are right, I am thinking about HTML emails customised for each recipient. May I ask you to be a little more specific on how you actually do it? Thank you.

Comment: which part are you confused about?

Comment: One can use django templating within the standalone python script, correct?  If not (and I honestly don't know why not, I'm not that familiar with django's  templating language), just use mako or cheetah.  These are text based templating languages with no arbitrary limits.

Comment: David, I figured it out how to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Good. As a SO user, you should either select an answer, or create your own to document what you did to solve your problem.